# Alternative to Interface w/ Ria Services

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

All of my Entities will have the following properties:

```
Employee CreatedBy { get; set; }
Employee ModifiedBy { get; set; }
DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
```

This is for a very large application and the entities are all pulled from different databases and, therefore, are in different `.edmx` files.

Mostly, these will be displayed in a `DataGrid` and I want to have a tooltip display all of that information.  `Employee` is a View that is in every database.

What I would normally do, would be to create an interface `IEmployee` that the `Employee` entity from each namespace would implement.  Then I would create an `IToolTipEnabled` interface with the properties listed above, and I would implement that wherever needed.

Then, I would be able to use a single converter on the Silverlight side for the tooltip content.  As it is, I would have to basically create a new converter for each entity type, in order to get the cast right.

**Is there a good way to do this?**

Thanks for taking the time to read this and for any help/insight you might be able to provide!

**EDIT: ken2k's solution is definitely the correct one, simply place the interfaces in a '.shared.cs' file and in that same shared file (or another *shared* file) put partial class definitions of the class implementing the interface.  That's all it takes.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some of your entities share common properties and you need to get those properties without having to know the type of the entity, then interfaces are indeed a good idea.

For example:

```
public interface IDatedEntity
{
    DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
}

public partial class User : IDatedEntity
{
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    ...
}
...
public partial class Customer : IDatedEntity
{
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

So you can use a single converter without having to know the actual entity:

```
// Returns the number of days since last update of an entity
public class DateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {       
        if (value is IDatedEntity)
        {
            return DateTime.UtcNow.Substract(((IDatedEntity)value).UpdateDate).TotalDays;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: But can this work with Ria Services?  I kept getting errors, then I found: http://forums.silverlight.net/t/173718.aspx/1 which seems to say that it is not possible...

Comment: @user468341 Try to save your partial classes (that implements your interface) in a file named XXX.shared.cs (for example User.shared.cs in the above example). This pattern is used by RIA service to automatically share C# code from server side to client side (code copied in the client proxy).

Comment: @ken2k If you do that, it almost works; it doesn't appear to send the property over the wire back to server-side.  I was SO close to having this work.